# Corollary 3.39 in Hatcher's book

Tags: algebraic-topology

Corollary 3.39 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology says the following:

> **Corollary 3.39.** If $M$ is a closed connected orientable $n$ manifold, then then an element $\alpha \in H^k(M;\mathbb{Z})$ generates an infinite cyclic summand of $H^k(M;\mathbb{Z})$ if and only if there exists an element $\beta \in H^{n-k}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\alpha \smile \beta$ is a generator of $H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. With coefficients in a field this holds for any $\alpha \neq 0$.

My question concerns the very last sentence: *"With coefficients in a field this holds for any $\alpha \neq 0$"*. What exactly does the author mean by this statement? I do not think the corresponding statement for fields is

> *If $M$ is a closed connected orientable $n$ manifold, then then an element $\alpha \in H^k(M;\mathbb{F})$ generates an infinite cyclic summand of $H^k(M;\mathbb{F})$ if and only if there exists an element $\beta \in H^{n-k}(M;\mathbb{F})$ such that $\alpha \smile \beta$ is a generator of $H^n(M;\mathbb{F})$*

If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, then we should get that $H^n(M;\mathbb{F}) \cong \mathbb{F}$ and saying that $\alpha \smile \beta$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}$ seems meaningless since $\mathbb{F}$ could, for example, be $\mathbb{Q} $ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it something like $\alpha \in H^k(M;\mathbb{F})$ is non-zero if and only if there exists a $\beta \in H^{n-k}(M;\mathbb{F})$ such that $\alpha \smile \beta$ is nonzero? That seems a bit odd as well.

Comment: For any rank 1 vector space $V$ over any field, any nonzero element $v \in V$ generates $V$, in the sense that $V$ is the smallest subspace of itself that contains $v$.